# Delete table row from database on clicking on html table's delete column's cell (td = x)

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I have html table which displays columns-client name, staff name and matter whereas in my database i have id,date,client_name,staff,matter columns. well that's not the problem. i wanted to delete the rows on button click so i just added a column delete which contains button with id-"del", and yes this column does not exist in my database. now I want to delete the rows from my table as well as database on the corresponding button click using Jquery. how do I do that?
 This is what I have tried so far-

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

$('#tableresult').on('click', '#del', (function(){
    var row = $(this).attr('id');
    $(#tableresult).removeRow(row);
});

});
```

n my html-

```
<td class="delete_td"><button id="del" btn btn-danger>&times;</button></td>
```

this is my html table code-

```
<table class="footable" data-filter="#filter" id="tableresult">
                               <thead>

                                <th>Client name</th>
                                 <th>Staff name</th>
                                 <th>Matter</th>
                                 <th> Delete</th>
                              </thead>

 <?php
include('db.php');
$sql=mysql_query("select * from newdata");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$id=$row['id'];
$clientname=$row['client_name'];
$staff=$row['staff'];
$matter=$row['matter'];

?>
<tr id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="edit_tr">

<td class="edit_td" >
<span id="client_<?php echo $id; ?>" class="text"><?php echo $clientname; ?></span>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $clientname; ?>" class="editbox" id="client_input_<?php echo $id; ?>" /&gt;
</td>

<td class="edit_td">
<span id="staff_<?php echo $id; ?>" class="text"><?php echo $staff; ?></span> 
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $staff; ?>" class="editbox" id="staff_input_<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
</td>

<td class="edit_td">
<span id="matter_<?php echo $id; ?>" class="text"><?php echo $matter; ?></span> 
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $matter; ?>" class="editbox" id="matter_input_<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
</td>

<td class="delete_td"><button id="del" btn btn-danger>&times;</button></td>

</tr>



<?php
}
?>

</tbody>
  <tfoot class="hide-if-no-paging">
    <th>                       </th>
     <th>
        <div class="pagination pagination-centered"></div>
     </th>
    <th>             </th>
    <th>             </th>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

this is my table_edit.js code-see if this has any relevance

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(".edit_tr").click(function()
{
var ID=$(this).attr('id');
$("#client_"+ID).hide();
$("#staff_"+ID).hide();
$("#matter_"+ID).hide();
$("#client_input_"+ID).show();
$("#staff_input_"+ID).show();
$("#matter_input_"+ID).show();
}).change(function()
{
var ID=$(this).attr('id');
var client=$("#client_input_"+ID).val();
var staff=$("#staff_input_"+ID).val();
var matter=$("#matter_input_"+ID).val();
var dataString = 'id='+ ID +'&clientname='+client+'&staff='+staff+'&matter='+matter;
//$("#client_"+ID).html('<img src="load.gif" />'); // Loading image

if(client.length>0 && staff.length>0 && matter.length>0)
{

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "table_edit_ajax.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{
$("#client_"+ID).html(client);
$("#staff_"+ID).html(staff);
$("#matter_"+ID).html(matter);
}
});
}
else
{
 alert('enter something');
}

});

// Edit input box click action
$(".editbox").mouseup(function() 
{
return false
});

// Outside click action
$(document).mouseup(function()
{
$(".editbox").hide();
$(".text").show();
});

});
```

Comment: you should call ajax for achieving that.

Comment: i m not that that comfortable with using ajax ..so please guide me with using that..

Comment: Did you mean each row has its own `delete` button? And if it clicked the associated row is removed, either from the html and database?

Comment: yes..they have their corresponding del buttons

Comment: according to your code you applied edit action on whole `tr` tag. while it should be at the particular column.

Comment: yes..but i will require that for my edit functionality because i want it to allow editing in the entire row on the click function at any place in the row

Comment: how do i allow editing only in first three column

Answer (score 0):

your js should be like

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#tableresult').on('click', '#del', (function () {
        var row = $(this).attr('id');

        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
                url: 'http://yoursite_url/delete.php',
                data: {id: row },
                success: function (result) {
                $('#'+row).remove();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

and delete.php

```
include 'config.php' // DB Connection
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE id = '$id'");
```

Comment: what is happening is that whenever i click on a particular table row it automatically switches to edit mode, this same thing happen if i click on delete button in my column,but does not delete anything

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$("#del").click(function () {
            var row = $(this).attr('temp_id');
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'http://yoursite_url/delete.php',
                data: {id: row},
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#row').remove();
                }
            });
        });
```

Change the button like this

```
<button id="del" temp_id="<?php echo $id; ?>"  class="btn btn-danger">&times;</button>
```

AND delete.php`include 'config.php';
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE id = '$id'");`

Comment: Bro you didn't think that you just copy whole code of mine.

Comment: only a minor thing i have changed i.e. to get the id of deleted row.. if You think Sorry ..